# How to auto increment a variable in sparql?

Tags: web-crawler, sparql, semantic-web, sparqlwrapper

I want to crawl 100 pages of wikipedia , so I want to increment the wikiPageID by 1, each time. How can i do it?

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  * WHERE {
?saket dbo:wikiPageID 57570.
?saket foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikilink.  

       OPTIONAL {
            ?saket dbp:birthPlace ?birth.}
       OPTIONAL {
            ?saket dbp:dateOfBirth ?dob.}
       OPTIONAL{
            ?saket dbp:nationality ?country.}
       OPTIONAL{
            ?saket dbp:occupation  ?occupation.}

}
```

Comment: Use a FILTER on the object instead of the value `57570`.

Comment: @AKSW Would you put an illustration in an Answer? I think I understand your advice, but would like to see your Answer so I too can test it.

Comment: @JayGray Instead of `?saket dbo:wikiPageID 57570.` do something like `?saket dbo:wikiPageID ?wikiPageId . filter (57570 <= ?wikiPageId && ?wikiPageId <= 57670)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

   SELECT  * WHERE {
   ?saket dbo:wikiPageID ?id .
   ?saket foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikilink.  
   FILTER(?id >= 100 && ?id < 200)

   OPTIONAL {
        ?saket dbp:birthPlace ?birth.}
   OPTIONAL {
        ?saket dbp:dateOfBirth ?dob.}
   OPTIONAL{
        ?saket dbp:nationality ?country.}
   OPTIONAL{
        ?saket dbp:occupation  ?occupation.}
   }
```